# AttributeError: 'Babel' object has no attribute 'localeselector'

Tags: python, babeljs

I tried to translate my web app with 'babel' but i trapped with the error:
"AttributeError: 'Babel' object has no attribute 'localeselector'"
I use python 3.11.1 and Babel 2.11.0
This is the code related to the problem.

```
from flask_babel import Babel, get_locale, gettext

@babel.localeselector
def determine_locale():
    if 'language' in session:
        return session['language']
    return request.accept_languages.best_match(['en', 'es'])
```

I succssesfully created all the files like (messages.pot, messages.po and messages.mo) using command promt. I think I have poor knowlages about decorators themselves, and can't figure out where to look to find solution.

I tried to import localeselector using different ways, and read a lot of examples from peoples who did manage with it. But still can'n get the point what the step I've missed.

Answer (score 12):

`@babel.localeselector` didn't work in my version of `Flask` and `flask_babel`. Use `init_app` instead:

```
babel.init_app(app, locale_selector=get_locale)
```

And make sure you defined `get_locale()` func before this call

See also [Flask-Babel: get_locale() seems to be not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229322/flask-babel-get-locale-seems-to-be-not-working)